# Unexpected behavior of preg_replace with OSX

Tags: php, regex, macos

According to the following piece of code, I'm wondering how a simple `preg_replace` intended to remove multiple whitespaces can turn the character `à` into a question mark:

```
$str = 'nnn      à    nnn     é  nnn';
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str) . "\n";
// outputs 'nnn ? nnn é nnn'
```

This occurs on a Mac using OSX 10.8.4. Any idea?

Comment: Almost certainly an encoding thing. Do you know your string's encoding?

Comment: It works for me in PHP Tester on OS X 10.6.8. I agree that it's probably a problem with your encoding.

Comment: Agree with you both. How can I accurately detect the encoding?

Comment: Just a wild guess and not sure if it will work, try the `u` modifier : `preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange.

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
$str = '   à   n';
file_put_contents('a.bin',preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str) . "\n");

file_put_contents('b.bin', 'à');
```

First, set up a test file containing `à`, named `c.bin`

```
$ php test.php
```

Then we cat files to compare :

```
$ cat b.bin
à$ cat c.bin
à
```

Files `b.bin` and `c.bin` contains `à` as expected

```
$ hexdump -C b.bin 
00000000  c3 a0                                             |..|
00000002
$ hexdump -C c.bin 
00000000  c3 a0 0a                                          |...|
<00000003></00000003>
```

Thanks to hexdump we can assume that `à` is `c3 a0`

```
$ cat a.bin 
 ? n
$ hexdump -C a.bin 
00000000  20 c3 20 6e 0a                                    | . n.|
00000005
```

In the first file, `a.bin`, there is no `a0` ([NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm)) and the accent is badly rendered

So it doesn't seem to be an encoding error

EDIT:
You could use mb_ereg_replace or the `u` modifier (as said by HamZa) :

```
$ cat test.php 
<?php
$str = 'nnn      à    nnn     é  nnn';
var_dump(preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $str));
var_dump(mb_ereg_replace('\s+', ' ', $str));
$ php test.php 
string(17) "nnn à nnn é nnn"
string(17) "nnn à nnn é nnn"
```

Comment: @davidloubere I believe, without the `u` modifier, `preg_replace` matches byte-wise. and `a0` is the non-breaking space, so it gets matched by `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encoding to UTF-8 in an HTML page with the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Since it's probably a problem with your encoding, that tag will probably fix it.